# Get the duration of continuous mouse movement

Tags: javascript, dom

Track the duration of continuous mouse movements on a webpage. A measurement begins when the cursor starts to move and ends when the cursor has stopped moving on the page. Reporting on duration happens thereafter. THis is what I have and works for while the mouse is moving and while it is stopped. However, I am confused how to track the start time and end time(i.e. the duration period of the mouse moving).

```
            var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
            var timeout;
            //var startTime;
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {

                myDiv.innerHTML = "You are moving";
                if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(mouseStop, 150);
            });

            function mouseStop() {
                myDiv.innerHTML = "Stopped";
                //console.log(Math.abs((startTime.getTime() - endTime.getTime())/1000));
            }
```

Comment: What are `startTime` and `endTime`?

Comment: I was trying to make startTime = new Date() and the same for endTime inside their relative functions, however, it is wrong approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count time on a different timer thread. Once you stop rest the timer.

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var timeout;
var timer = {stopped: true, time: 0};

setInterval(() => {
  if (!timer.stopped) {
    timer.time++;
  }
}, 1000);

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
  timer.stopped = false;
  myDiv.innerHTML = "You are moving";
  if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(mouseStop, 150);
});

function mouseStop() {
  var totalTime = timer.time;
  timer = {stopped: true, time: 0};
  myDiv.innerHTML = 'Stopped! Total time: ' + totalTime + ' seconds';
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```